# Rails 18n French: Special Characters appear when words with accent are being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, rails-i18n, reason-react

I added french translation using i18n gem. Most of the french words with accent characters get printed correctly but some of the words are behaving incorrectly.

`SÃ©curitÃ©` gets printed instead of `Sécurité`. I tried to escape the accented characters with backticks or double single quotes but was unable to achieve the correct result.

In `.re` file:
`<h3 className="text-lg font-semibold"> {t("security") |> str} </h3>`

In `.yml` file:
`security: "Sécurité"`

Comment: This appears to be a **character encoding** problem; you're mixing up `latin-1` (ISO 8859-1) with `utf-8`. Check what encoding your database table is using, and that you're not forcing data into incorrect encodings elsewhere.

Comment: The issue is not with DB. I'm just trying to display the word on frontend. It's not coming from DB.

Comment: I can guarantee you that **something** is screwing up character encoding. (The fix isn't to insert a backslash or similar.) You didn't actually show any code, so I can only speculate where the problem originates -- I'd check at what point precisely the character is rendering wrong, and then investigate why the character encoding is wrong at the point.

Comment: @TomLord added code in the question.

Comment: So it's probably something in React that renders the page as latin-1, instead of utf-8? If you google rendering UTF-8 in react (I'm no expert in this specifically), you'll find a whole load of people complaining about an almost identical problem to yours. Possibly [adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the header](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7tppu3/how_to_handle_special_characters/) fixes it?